# how to remove my computer icon, home folder, and trash bin from desktop

Tags: icons, gconf

In a previous version of Ubuntu, I used gconf-editor to add icons to the desktop, but now gconf looks confusing. How can I remove the *My Computer*, *Home Folder*, and *Trash* icons from my desktop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming you are using Ubuntu 11.10? If you go to the software center you can download "advanced settings" which will allow you to turn on and off those desktop icons. I don't know why they are on there, as I thought on default the desktop doesn't have any icons, but rather they are on the unity bar.

Comment: it was an upgrade... it used to be ease to put them and remove them from there, now I have to learn my way around all over again, but after all, it looks good!

Comment: @mia_tech did this answer your question? If so, remember to click the "Accept Answer" button (the checkmark).